# Why can I loop over an immutable iterator with for construct?

Tags: iterator, rust

For learning purposes, I'm trying to `match` over an iterator's `next()` method.

If I declare the iterator as immutable like in the following snippet, the compiler yells at me saying that I have to use `let mut x_iter` instead:

```
let x = vec![1, 2, 3];
let x_iter = x.iter();

loop {
    match x_iter.next() {
        Some(v) => { println!("{}", v); }
        None    => { println!("end"); break; }
    }
}
```

This triggers the following error:

```
error: cannot borrow immutable local variable `x_iter` as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:6:15
  |
3 |     let x_iter = x.iter();
  |         ------ use `mut x_iter` here to make mutable
...
6 |         match x_iter.next() {
  |               ^^^^^^ cannot borrow mutably
```

If I use `let mut x_iter = ...` instead, then everything works.

How come I *have* to declare `x_iter` as mutable in the first place, since I'm not mutating it in the `match` block?

One would argue that somehow, the `next()` method *is* indeed altering the iterator, as it needs to increment the pointer to its next element. That would make a compelling argument for using a mutable iterator.

However, wouldn't that also be the case when using `for v in x_iter { }`? This construct definitely works with an immutable iterator. Is it simply because the `for` construct modifies the pointer *internally* and then leaves the object unchanged for the outside world, while using `next()` manually triggers a mutation which is, this time, visible from the outside world?

Comment: [Here's a post](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3azc4n/how_does_for_loop_get_a_mutable_iterator/) (from reddit) that explains why using an immutable iterator works with for loops.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Why don't you write a full answer?

Comment: @Boiethios I've only dabbled in Rust and do not feel confident in it. I would much rather leave this in the hands of someone who is familiar with the language, as they may have some further insight that I have overlooked (may even be a duplicate). Feel free to take the spotlight!